# The project file was unloaded - C# windows forms project

Tags: visual-studio

The picture below shows the problem.
"The project file can't be uploaded"

I have no Idea what could cause this, but you should know that I formatted my computer several times before the problem occurred.

[The solution explorer of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0cks.png)

I tried opening the project in a visual studio Enterprise "Cracked" version, and it worked well, so does that mean the problem is related to the community version?.

Comment: Whatever the issue, you will probably find more details in the output window (Try setting "Show output from:" to "General")

Comment: I find it to be empty (the "Show output from:").

Comment: Even after attempting to reload the project?

Comment: When I reload the project; the installer opens a window that says: "You already have the frameworks, SDKs, and tools installed that you need for the development work you selected. You can always add more by running 'Visual Studio Installer'"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.